# Pandas Series: Log Normalize

Tags: python, pandas, normalization

I have a Pandas Series, that needs to be log-transformed to be normal distributed. But I can´t log transform yet, because there are values =0 and values below 1 (0-4000). Therefore I want to normalize the Series first. I heard of StandardScaler(scikit-learn), Z-score standardization and Min-Max scaling(normalization).
I want to cluster the data later, which would be the best method?
StandardScaler and Z-score standardization use mean, variance etc. Can I use them on "not yet normal distibuted" data?

Comment: 1 < values < 1 - i.e. your data set is empty? :-p

Comment: My Data is from 0 to 4000, values below 1 will get negative with Log Transformation. The zeros are also a problem, because I will get -inf, which will lead to Problems with the histogram

Answer (score 17):

To transform to logarithms, you need positive values, so translate your range of values (-1,1] to normalized (0,1] as follows

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(-1,1,(10,1)))
df['norm'] = (1+df[0])/2 # (-1,1] -> (0,1]
df['lognorm'] = np.log(df['norm'])
```

results in a dataframe like

```
          0      norm   lognorm
0  0.360660  0.680330 -0.385177
1  0.973724  0.986862 -0.013225
2  0.329130  0.664565 -0.408622
3  0.604727  0.802364 -0.220193
4  0.416732  0.708366 -0.344795
5  0.085439  0.542719 -0.611163
6 -0.964246  0.017877 -4.024232
7  0.738281  0.869141 -0.140250
8  0.558220  0.779110 -0.249603
9  0.485144  0.742572 -0.297636
```

Answer (score 6):

If your data is in the range (-1;+1) (assuming you lost the minus in your question) then **log transform is probably not what you need**. At least from a theoretical point of view, it's obviously the *wrong* thing to do.

Maybe your data has already been preprocessed (inadequately)? Can you get the raw data? **Why do you think log transform will help?**

If you don't care about what is the meaningful thing to do, you can call `log1p`, which is the same as `log(1+x)` and which will thus work on (-1;∞).